# How open iframe in php

Tags: php, iframe

```
<?php
    $url=$_GET['url'];
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($host === 'example.com')
    { 
        //open $url in iframe
    } else {//code }
?>
```

How can I open a url in iframe in php,

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to open url on half page if it is example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an iframe if the if condition is true:

```
<?php
    $url=$_GET['url'];
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($host === 'example.com')
    { 
        //open $url in iframe
        ?>
        <iframe src="<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>
        <?php
    } else {//code }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $url=$_GET['url'];
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($host === 'example.com')
    { 
        echo '<iframe src="'.$url.'" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>';
    } 
?>
```